# Select * from table where id != long_list

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

**NOTE**: I'm using SQLAlchemy but I've chosen to translate my idea into regular SQL so that more people can answer / read this question.

I am attempting to select all entries in a table which are not in a filter. I'm getting the filter by associating a user_id to a table_id. I currently have a working implementation using,

`select * from cleared_table where user_id=user_id`

and then I construct a second select statement saying,

```
select * from table where table_id != first_id and table_id != second_id ....
```

**I'm looking for a way to condense this down into a single SQL statement rather then having to make two trips to the database.**

Example cleared_table,

```
cleared_table
user_id | table_id
1       |        1
1       |        2
1       |        3
2       |        2
3       |        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a nested query.

```
select * from table where table_id not in (select table_id from cleared_table where user_id=user_id)
```

Comment: well now I just feel dumb. a sub-select is what I need to do.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to talk it out :) If I helped can you up vote the answers please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN` and a subquery:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    table
where 
    table_id not in (select 
                         table_id 
                     from 
                         cleared_table where user_id=user_id)
```

Comment: This still requires me to acquire the id's in the first select statement.